# Android get path for image from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I made an app and implemented picking a picture from gallery.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Is there any valid method that extracts the **right path** for the `new File(path)` based `onActivityResult` `Uri` ?? By meaning right path i means it considers also the moment when there are different sdk targeted (15+). I tried from different sources, but they crashed when targeting multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Uri like this, what you are normally expected to do is read it through an InputStream:

```
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Then you can work with the image content after you read it.  You won't have access to the underlying file for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code you can upload compressed image with proper URL:

In your `OnActivityResult()` method:

```
case PHOTO_PICKER_ID:
                        if (requestCode == PHOTO_PICKER_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                            compressImage(getPath(selectedImage));
                            f= new File(filename);
                            uploadImage();
                    }
```

After that:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri)
        {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null)
                return null;
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return s;
        }


public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }

    public String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```